# How to force applyBindings in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to refresh model binding for my page. As says documentation I use applyBindings method.
Also I need to use few viewModels on a page. To do it I use object-wrapper + "with" keyword on binding:

```
ko.applyBindings({ model1: {...}, model2: {...} });

<div data-bind="with: $root.model1"> ... </div>
<div data-bind="with: $root.model2"> ... </div>
```

It works fine until I don't use dynamic bindings update. If I try to add additional viewmodels on a page, it doesn't work :(

Few pieces of code:

**1) Works fine:**

```
$("#b1").click(function () {
ko.applyBindings({
    myModel1: {
        MyText: ko.observable("Some text")
    },
    myModel2: {
        MyText: ko.observable("Some text")
    }
});
```

});

```
$("#b2").click(function () {
    ko.applyBindings({
        myModel1: {
            MyText: ko.observable("Some other text")
        },
        myModel2: {
            MyText: ko.observable("Some other text 2")
        }
    });
});
```

**2) Doesn't work:**

```
$("#b1").click(function () {
ko.applyBindings({
    myModel1: {
        MyText: ko.observable("Some text")
    }
});
```

});

```
$("#b2").click(function () {
    ko.applyBindings({
        myModel1: {
            MyText: ko.observable("Some other text")
        },
        myModel2: {
            MyText: ko.observable("Some other text 2")
        }
    });
});
```

As I understand, we have no way to bind additional view models in such manner. I also tried to use "ko.cleanNode()" method, but it doesn't work too.
Full sample of code stored at http://jsfiddle.net/eN8dq/2/

Can you suggest me true way how I can add additional view model on a page? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this case: https://github.com/sergun/Knockout-MultiModels

Any comments?

Comment: This should work out well and would have been my answer had I seen the question sooner.

Comment: Can the bindings be made in theory? e.g. the actual #element does not exist, until in later a future ajax update

Answer (score 2):

try not to force bindings, but change value for already bound model:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.myModel1 = ko.observable( {
        MyText: ko.observable("Some other text")
    });

    self.myModel2 = ko.observable({
        MyText: ko.observable("Some other text 2")
    });


    self.clickAction = function() {
        //do the trick of assigning value
        self.myModel1 ({
            MyText: ko.observable("Some another text")
        });
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: No, unfortunately. I don't know how many viewmodels I will need in the future on first applyBindinds call.

Comment: Have you thought about using observableArray of observable view models?

Comment: I can't imagine how it can works. Can you provide small piece of code?